# Is wait_for_service required before every service call?

Tags: ros, rospy, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I don't fully understand the mechanics of rospy's wait_for_service function. Are we required to call wait for service every time we want to call the service, or only once when creating the ServiceProxy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263440/is-wait_for_service-required-before-every-service-call?/) by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.ros.org/users/28842/hamzamerzic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2017-06-08

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to call `wait_for_service`, but it is highly advisable, since you want to make sure that your service is available before calling it.

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2017-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hamzamerzic](https://answers.ros.org/users/28842/hamzamerzic/) on 2017-06-08**:
What can cause the service to become unavailable?

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-06-08**:
Too many things actually. From connection problems to bad code handling that would kill the node that runs the service. Keep in mind that you can set a timeout in `wait_for_services` after which an exception will be thrown.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-06-08**:
The most common reason is at startup that the other node has not yet advertised the service or the connection has not been established.

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-06-08**:
Thanks for your input!